# Good lower-bounds for $\inf_{f(x) \le \epsilon} g(x)$ and $\inf_{g(x) \le \epsilon} f(x)$ where $f(x):=\|x-a\|$ and $g(x) := f(x) + r\|x\|$.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, upper-lower-bounds

Fix $a \in \mathbb R^n$, $r \ge 0$, and $\epsilon \ge 0$, and consider the functions given by $f(x) := \|x-a\|_2$ and $g(x) = f(x) + r\|x\|_2$, for $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Let $S(f) := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid f(x) \le \epsilon\}$.

**Question.** As a function of $r$, $\epsilon$, and $a$, what are some generally good lower-bounds for $\inf_{x \in S(f)} g(x)$ and $\inf_{x \in S(g)} f(x)$  ?

### An obvious lower-bound

- It is clear that
  $$
  \begin{split}
  \inf_{x \in S(f)} g(x) &\ge \epsilon + \min_{\|x-a\|_2 \le \epsilon} r\|x\|_2 = \epsilon + r\max(\|a\|_2-\epsilon,0)\\
  &=
  \begin{cases}\epsilon,&\mbox{ if }\|a\|_2\le \epsilon,\\(1-r)\epsilon + r\|a\|_2,&\mbox{ else.}
  \end{cases}
  \end{split}
  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer, computing $\inf_{x \in S(f)} g(x)$ exactly.

Let $C = \operatorname{conv}\{0, a\} \subseteq L$ and $p_C(x)$ be the projections of $x$ onto $C$. Since projection onto a convex set is non-expansive, we have
\begin{align*}
g(p_C(x)) &= \|p_C(x) - a\| + r\|p_C(x)\| \\
&= \|p_C(x) - p_C(a)\| + r\|p_C(x) - p_C(0)\| \\
&\le \|x - a\| + r\|x - 0\| \\
&= g(x).
\end{align*}
Now, using this same non-expansiveness, we can also conclude that if $\|x - a\| \le \varepsilon$, then
$$\|p_C(x) - a\| = \|p_C(x) - p_C(a)\| \le \|x - a\| \le \varepsilon.$$
So, if $x \in S(f)$, then $p_C(x) \in S(f)$. Thus, assuming for the moment that $a \neq 0$,
\begin{align*}
\inf_{\|x - a\| \le \varepsilon} g(x) &= \inf_{\substack{\|x - a\| \le \varepsilon \\ x \in C}} g(x) = \inf_{\substack{\|x - a\| \le \varepsilon \\ x = \lambda a \\ 0 \le \lambda \le 1}} g(x) \\
&= \inf_{\substack{\max\{0, 1 - \varepsilon/\|a\|\} \le \lambda \le 1}} g(\lambda a) \\
&= \inf_{\substack{\max\{0, 1 - \varepsilon/\|a\|\} \le \lambda \le 1}} (1 - \lambda + r\lambda)\|a\| \\
&= \|a\| + \|a\|\inf_{\substack{\max\{0, 1 - \varepsilon/\|a\|\} \le \lambda \le 1}} \lambda(r - 1) \\
&= \|a\| + \|a\|\begin{cases} (r - 1)\max\left\{0, 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{\|a\|}\right\} & \text{if } r > 1 \\ r - 1  & \text{if }r \le 1\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases} \|a\| + (r - 1)\max\{0, \|a\| - \varepsilon\} & \text{if } r > 1 \\ r\|a\|  & \text{if }r \le 1\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
If we relax the $a \neq 0$ assumption, then the above conclusion clearly still holds, by considering the $a = 0$ case separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it's not clear why $\inf_{x \in S(f)} g(x) = \inf_{x \in S(f) \cap C}g(x)$.

Comment: @dohmatob Because, for any particular $x \in S(f)$, the projection $p_C(x)$ lies in $S(f) \cap C$, and satisfies $g(p_C(x)) \le g(x)$. That is, for any point $S(f)$, there is a point in $C \cap S(f)$ with the same or lesser value of $g$. Thus, the minimum over $S(f)$ must occur on $S(f) \cap C$.

Comment: Oops!, of course. Thanks again.